# JQuery mobile data-native-menu="false" popup and changePage

Tags: jquery-mobile, select-menu

So this is kind of a weird issue...  I'm using JQuery mobile 1.4 and I am getting some unusual behavior.  Here's what I have...
On my main page is a selectmenu with the data-native-menu set to false.  The selectmenu (which is dynamically set) can sometimes have a lot of elements.  When it does, the menu becomes a popup.  I have another page that is accessed from a button using

```
$.mobile.changePage('#lbsPage', {transition:'flip'} );
```

Here's the strange part.  When I go to the lbsPage from the main page, go back, then access the selectmenu (with the popup values), after selecting an option it goes back to the previous page.
Now in case this explanation sucks, here's a [link](http://www.whitesoup12.com/lbs) to my site where you can see it for yourself.  
Here's what you can do...
  Go to Menu -> Import BeerXML -> Back.  Then go to The Fermentables -> Select 'Grain' from the Type menu -> Then open and select anything from the Fermentable menu.  You'll notice that it goes back to the Import BeerXML page.  
What causes this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to find the solution to my problem.  For some reason that I don't remember, I set the configuration option hashListeningEnabled to false.  After removing that option (which defaults to true), my page is reacting as it should.